# Remove values outside of axis range?

Tags: limit

Alright, I have a basic script to plot trajectories of an object.  I have basic equations of motion solving the position of the object with respect to time.  The plot itself is a 3D representation of the trajectory of the object.

I've successfully got the axis limits set, and now I want to make sure I don't see any values for this trajectory that fall OUTSIDE the axis limits.  Right now, the trajectory falls below the x-y plane and continues downwards, outside of the 3D plot...  Is there any way to prevent this?

Here's the entire code:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mpl.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 10

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')


### Define Variables ###
time = (10)     #Time to calculate the equations
t = np.linspace(0, time, 100)

g = (9.81)      #Gravity

vxo = (3)       #initial velocity in the x-direction
vyo = (1)       #initial velocity in the y-direction
vzo = (0)       #initial velocity in the z-direction

xo = (0)        #initial x-position
yo = (0)        #initial y-position
zo = (9)        #initial z-position


### Equations of Motion ###
x = (xo + (vxo * t))
y = (yo + (vyo * t))
z = (10 - (.5 * g * (t**2)))


ax.plot(x, y, z, label=('Trajectory of Soccer Ball ' + str(time)))
ax.legend()

### Set axis limits ###
ax.set_xlim3d(0,10)
ax.set_ylim3d(0,10)
ax.set_zlim3d(0,10)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

If your object is going beyond the limits of your axis; it is because the equations are telling it to do that. You'll have to constraint your results and filter before plotting them. Something like:

```
x = equation1()
if( x > someLimit )
  handle error / object bounces by inverting the direction perhaps
plot(x)
```